# How to create a Second database connection with Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to connect a second database to my project in Symfony2. First, I added into `parameters.yml` some parameters to create the connection.

Then, I edited my `config.yml`, and now looks like:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
            circutor3:
                driver:   pdo_sqlsrv
                host:     "%database_host_circutor3%"
                port:     "%database_port_circutor%"
                dbname:   "%database_name_circutor%"
                user:     "%database_user_circutor3%"
                password: "%database_password_circutor3%"
                charset:  UTF8
orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

Finally, I tried to get connected, using the following code in my controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('circutor3');
```

And, the error returned by Symfony2:

> Doctrine ORM Manager named "circutor3" does not exist.

The circutor3 makes connection to a database, external to my system, so I don't need to create entities or objects. I only need to execute some `SELECT` to get information and store it using an array.

Is creating a typical `mysqli` connection the best way to solve my problem?
I don't know how to solve this with Symfony.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could access to the database connection in the controller as follow:

```
    $connection = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection('circutor3');
```

then use the connection as:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Some help [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#fetchall) and [here](https://www.thedevfiles.com/2014/08/simplifying-database-interactions-with-doctrine-dbal/)

Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

According to Symfony documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html), you only defined a connection, not an entity manager :

You have to create an entity_manager for each connection.

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            ...
        circutor3:
            connection: circutor3
            mappings:
                AppBundle: ~
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I only need to execute some queries, so I only need to create the connection, not an entuty manager. I appreciate your reply anyway :)